# Convert inserted string in date format of sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

is it possible to if i am inserted '15-05-2018 16:09:21' in this format or any other format like '05-15-2018 16:09:21' etc. and at insert time in table it will convert in '2018-05-15 16:09:21' in this format in SQL server which format is accept by SQL for insert? if possible then how to do it?

Comment: You should insert date/time values into date/time columns.  I would recommend inserting the value you really want.

Comment: no but this string is coming from web service,so i want to convert it in date format

Comment: 16:09:21 to 16:09:36?

Comment: @NimishaPrajapati, use parameterized queries with a datetime parameter and datetime column.

Comment: When you insert data you can user [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) , maybe try Convert(datetime2,'15-05-2018 16:09:21',126)

Comment: You should convert your string into a datetime as *early* as possible after it's input - that should be somewhere within your webservice. If you're going to display that date to a user, do that as *late* as possible towards output - again, somewhere in your webservice is indicated. Everywhere else, you should be working with datetime variables/parameters/columns. If you *stop* using strings, you'll *stop* having issues relating to *formats*, which you should realise *don't* exist in native datetime types (which usually just store a single number representing fixed intervals since some past day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be stored as `datetime` in columns which is good practice always.
To convert from above format, you can try this.

```
 SELECT Cast(Convert(datetime,'15-05-2018 16:09:21',103) as datetime);
 SELECT convert( varchar(20),Convert(datetime,'15-05-2018 16:09:21',103) ,120)
```

Comment: datatype of your column in the table ? and what error you are getting ?

Comment: it is datetime so need to convert it in sql date format 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'this is error i get

Comment: I would say add your query to the question, i guess either your data is not in string format with correct spaces to convert as datetime or u have a where clause in your query filtering dates. Try updated script with additional cast

Comment: sir i dont need date in SELECT Convert(datetime,'15-05-2018 16:09:21',103); this format i need it in  '2018-05-15 16:09:36' this format only

Comment: If i understood correctly, u don't need milliseconds to be added from datetime, so added another script to the solution

Comment: thanks it is working fine.i have fixed the format of date which is coming from web service and apply your script.so it's working.

Comment: @NimishaPrajapati Please accept answer if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
declare @dataWeb varchar(max) = '15-05-2018 16:09:21' 
declare @dataSql varchar(max) = '2018-05-15 16:09:36' 


select @dataWeb
 , @dataSql
 , format(cast(@dataWeb as datetime),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') dataFormat
```

Comment: i dont't have static string of date it will be come in any format

Comment: It will be hard to handle any format, don't you have an interface contract within your webservice?